# How we can create a Table with "Clustered by" column using BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to create a Table using BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator with cluster_by column in my GCP composer task using python script. I am using "cluster_fields" to create column but its not working. Please suggest me What is the correct way ??

Below code which I am using.

```
stop_op = BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator(
        task_id='BigQuery_CreateTable',
        dataset_id=dataset_nm,
        table_id=table_nm,
        project_id=project_nm,
        schema_fields=[{"name": "emp_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
                       {"name": "salary", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                       {"name": "distribution_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                       {"name": "transaction_date", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE"}],
    time_partitioning={'type': 'DAY', 'field': 'transaction_date'},
    cluster_fields='distribution_name',
    bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='bigquery_default',
    autodetect=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this feature is not available in the latest version of Airflow (1.10.5 while writing this answer).

However, you can use create a new operator as below and use that.

```py
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults 
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook 
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook, _parse_gcs_url
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator 
import json

class BQCreateEmptyTableWithClusteredFieldsOp(BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator):
    template_fields = ('dataset_id', 'table_id', 'project_id',
                       'gcs_schema_object', 'labels')
    ui_color = '#f0eee4'

    # pylint: disable=too-many-arguments
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 dataset_id,
                 table_id,
                 project_id=None,
                 schema_fields=None,
                 gcs_schema_object=None,
                 time_partitioning=None,
                 bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
                 google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
                 delegate_to=None,
                 labels=None,
                 encryption_configuration=None,
                 cluster_fields=None,
                 *args, **kwargs):

        super(BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.project_id = project_id
        self.dataset_id = dataset_id
        self.table_id = table_id
        self.schema_fields = schema_fields
        self.gcs_schema_object = gcs_schema_object
        self.bigquery_conn_id = bigquery_conn_id
        self.google_cloud_storage_conn_id = google_cloud_storage_conn_id
        self.delegate_to = delegate_to
        self.time_partitioning = {} if time_partitioning is None else time_partitioning
        self.labels = labels
        self.encryption_configuration = encryption_configuration
        self.cluster_fields = cluster_fields or []

    def execute(self, context):
        bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.bigquery_conn_id,
                               delegate_to=self.delegate_to)

        if not self.schema_fields and self.gcs_schema_object:

            gcs_bucket, gcs_object = _parse_gcs_url(self.gcs_schema_object)

            gcs_hook = GoogleCloudStorageHook(
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id=self.google_cloud_storage_conn_id,
                delegate_to=self.delegate_to)
            schema_fields = json.loads(gcs_hook.download(
                gcs_bucket,
                gcs_object).decode("utf-8"))
        else:
            schema_fields = self.schema_fields

        conn = bq_hook.get_conn()
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.create_empty_table(
            project_id=self.project_id,
            dataset_id=self.dataset_id,
            table_id=self.table_id,
            schema_fields=schema_fields,
            time_partitioning=self.time_partitioning,
            labels=self.labels,
            cluster_fields=self.cluster_fields,
            encryption_configuration=self.encryption_configuration
        )
```

Now you can use that as follows:

```py
stop_op = BQCreateEmptyTableWithClusteredFieldsOp(
        task_id='BigQuery_CreateTable',
        dataset_id=dataset_nm,
        table_id=table_nm,
        project_id=project_nm,
        schema_fields=[{"name": "emp_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
                       {"name": "salary", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                       {"name": "distribution_name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                       {"name": "transaction_date", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE"}],
    time_partitioning={'type': 'DAY', 'field': 'transaction_date'},
    cluster_fields='distribution_name',
    bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='bigquery_default',
    autodetect=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, When I am using BQCreateEmptyTableWithClusteredFieldsOp class, I am getting error : No module named 'airflow.gcp'. I am using below imports ......

Comment: from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults                                                             
     from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
     from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook
     from airflow.gcp.hooks.gcs import _parse_gcs_url
    from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import 
    BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator  
    import json

Comment: Check the updated answer, I have added the imports in the code.

```
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults 
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook 
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook, _parse_gcs_url
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryCreateEmptyTableOperator 
import json
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but still Error is persist. ERROR - create_empty_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cluster_fields'

Comment: You might be using an older version of Airflow. `cluster_fields` is available to `create_empty_table()` in Airflow 1.10.5. Link: 

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.5/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L235

Comment: okay, Actually I am using GCP composer where we have airflow till version 1.10.2.that is the reason not able to use newest version of airflow. anyway Thank you for your solution